# MapDb 3.0 Pump Example

Tags: java, mapdb

Can anyone provide pump API example usage for mapdb 3.0 ?

Something similar to [this in 1.0.9](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/blob/mapdb-1.0.9/src/test/java/examples/Huge_Insert.java)

Answer (score 0):

Pump is discussed here:

https://jankotek.gitbooks.io/mapdb/content/btreemap/import.html

You need to use db.treeMap("aa").createFrom(some iterator)

Comment: Thanks. So what will correspond to pump.sort() from mapdb 1 in mapdb 3, because my iterator does not provide sorted items.